# Using threads to do multiple things without having a thread for each

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a class which basically does the same series of steps twice. Sounds like a perfect example of where to multithread your program. My question is though if I can do this with only two threads. Here is the general jist of things

```
Tester implements Runnable{
    Thread obj1Thread, obj2Thread;
    MyObj obj1, obj2;
    String obj1Results, obj2Results;

    void runTests(){
        obj1Thread = new Thread(this, "ob1 thread");
        obj2Thread = new Thread(this, "ob2 thread");
        obj1.start();//builds up obj1
        obj2.start();//builds up obj2
        if(obj1 and obj2 are finished building){
            System.out.println(obj1);
            System.out.println(obj2);
        }
        obj1Thread.startSecondPhase()//runs a separate function that tests obj1 vs ob2. Essentially test(ob1, ob2)
        obj2Thread.startSecondPhase()//runs a separate function that tests obj2 vs ob1. Essentially test(ob2, ob1)
        if(obj1 and obj2 are finished testing){
            System.out.println(obj1Results);
            System.out.println(obj2Results);
        }     
    }
}
```

I have gotten the first part - building up the objects - working. My questions are now -

1. How can I get the main thread to wait for the two threads to finish their first part? Perhaps the main would do a `wait` on both objects and then after the threads `notifyAll` they do a wait on the main thread? But then how do the threads get a hold of the main thread? Perhaps with `this`?
2. How can I have this 'second phase' of the run function without making a new class with a new thread and a new specific run function? I dont want to have to make a new class and everything for every little task.

To clarify the sequence of events I want specifically is -

1. Main thread initializes and starts two threads
2. Both threads simultaneously build their respective objects
3. When both threads finish building they pause. Then main thread prints the objects out in order.
4. After main thread is done, the two threads continue their code to a testing phase simultaneously
5. When the threads are done the main thread prints the results out. Could probably use a `join()` here

Edit: Also, how can I tell the specific threads which objects I want them to work on? Right now Im doing it in a kinda hacky way (i'm working off the thread name).

Comment: 1- [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) 2- You could use some kind of flag to tell the `Thread`/`Runnable` which run state it is

Comment: So you are saying have an `if/else` in the run function? `if(buildComplete) do test`? I'de prefer a more eloquent solution, but I suppose that works if there is nothing else.

Comment: Then use two `Runnables`, one for the build and one for the test - but you said you didn't want to do that...

Comment: Yes, but only because I feel like its kind of a waste and its ugly code. A special `Runnable` class just to implement basically one line of code? Perhaps I'm being too idealistic but that feels wrong to me.

Comment: You COULD use a `CountDownLatch` in the two threads (the main thread will be blocking on it), once you add to the count (in your thread) you could lock on another monitor lock that the main thread then updates (you could, for example, use a second `CountDownLatch` set to 1 for example)...This would mean you would end up with 3 `CountDownLatches`, build, wait and test...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use higher-level abstractions: use an execute and `ExecutorService.invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)`, which returns a list of `Future`.

Your main thread can

1. dispatch two tasks,
2. obtain two futures,
3. print the results, then
4. dispatch two more tasks

The executor service and futures will handle all the concurrency under the hood.

**EDIT**:

I see your comment:

> A special Runnable class just to implement basically one line of code?
>   Perhaps I'm being too idealistic but that feels wrong to me.

You typically use ananymous inner classes in such case:

```
Future future = executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Asynchronous task");
    }
});
```

Nothing wrong with that. When Java has lambda it will become even shorter.

```
  Future future = executorService.submit(() -> {System.out.println("Asynchronous task");});
```

Comment: +1 for the use of the `ExecutorService`.  IMHO, I don't see the issue with separating the the two tasks into separate classes, but that's just me

Comment: Im not really familiar with the `ExecutorService` stuff, do you know which implementing class I should use? I think a `threadPool` would be fine, but Im not 100% sure.

Comment: @Dgrin91 Yes. I guess `Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 2 )` should work. Also, I would benchmark to make sure the multi-threaded version is actually faster ;)

Comment: @ewernli I did, and its ~30% faster. And `newFixThreadPool` is what I ended up using.